# IIS hang while creating Excel file from large DB query

Tags: sql, iis, vbscript, asp-classic, application-pool

I have legacy code from ASP and IIS with OLE.DB connection as site configuration, and whenever large query request for downloading data file (as html but in Excel extension) IIS is not responding all other request till it finish or terminate. Being checked to increase virtual memory or application pool size, but it cannot be helped. Just suspecting that it might be IIS limitation of large blob handling, but have no idea how to solve or get around this matter yet. Please help for what can it be done or how it can be prevent from denial of requests while creating big data file in IIS.

- What should I check for IIS side where should be fixed?
- the Code refactoring for prevent IIS hang
- Any other suggestion for get around...

Unfortunately this was legacy system and our system engineers claimed no experiences about on such. Moreover ASP seems not much of resources available to solve similar from the web yet.

ASP code as below are the actual, and "sReportType=1" works fine because it is only handle small amount of data without any trouble. (It is still suspect that it harms operation though, but because of its size are comparatively smaller than...) However, when "sReportType=2" runs, IIS is only serve this request and not responding other requests.

I do understand even with current Excel limitation it only allow to contain 15000 lows and cut off data before hands also, but no use. I had changed TTL for http connection for large data also, and did not work. Modified application pool of IIS improve a little but refusal of other connection happened as same, while getting large data from DB. Sometimes even html tag is not finished when its download completed.

Do appreciate for help in advance.

```
<%@ Language=VBScript%>
<% On Error Resume next

setsize     = 10
    
Set DbCon   = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
DbCon.Open("Provider=OLEDB...) 'DB Connection String

...

sReportType = Request("sReportType") 'receive report type
if sReportType = "" then    
    sReportType = "1"   
end if

' Getting input value from request
sHospCd         = Request("sHospCd")
sName           = Request("sName")
sCHART_NO       = Request("sCHART_NO")
sSex            = Request("sSex")
sCZP_KIND       = Request("sCZP_KIND")

sStartDate      = Request("sStartDate")
sEndDate        = Request("sEndDate")
sSTOP_KIND      = Request("sSTOP_KIND")

If sReportType = "1" then           
    sPA_LAB_DATE        = Request("sPA_LAB_DATE")
    ePA_LAB_DATE        = Request("ePA_LAB_DATE")
    sPA_QUERY_YN        = Request("sPA_QUERY_YN")

    sPA_UPDATE_DATE     = Request("sPA_UPDATE_DATE")
    ePA_UPDATE_DATE     = Request("ePA_UPDATE_DATE")
End If 

If sReportType = "2" then           'Baseline
    sFU_LAB_DATE        = Request("sFU_LAB_DATE")
    eFU_LAB_DATE        = Request("eFU_LAB_DATE")
    sFU_QUERY_YN        = Request("sFU_QUERY_YN")
    
    sFU_UPDATE_DATE     = Request("sFU_UPDATE_DATE")
    eFU_UPDATE_DATE     = Request("eFU_UPDATE_DATE")
End If
...
...
subSQL = ""
subSQL2 = ""
qTitle = " Search Item [ "

if sReportType = "1" then   
    subSQL = subSQL & " FROM PATIENT P WHERE 1 = 1 "

    subSQL2 = subSQL2 & " ,P.HOSP_TRANS,P.HOSP_TRANS_NM,             " 
    subSQL2 = subSQL2 & " P.LAB_DATE,P.WBC,DECODE(P.WBC_UNIT,'1','/mm<sup>3</sup>','2','/L','') AS WBC_UNIT,P.SEG_NEUTRO,P.BANDS,P.ANC,P.INIT_DATE,                  " 
    subSQL2 = subSQL2 & " GETMNM('6002',P.CZP_KIND) CZP_KIND, GETMNM('6003',P.CZP_WEEK) CZP_WEEK,P.CZP_S_DATE,P.CZP_E_DATE,P.NEXT_LAB_DATE,P.DOCTOR_NM,P.DOCTOR_EMAIL,P.PHARMA_NM,           " 
    subSQL2 = subSQL2 & " P.PHARMA_EMAIL,P.INPUT_NM,P.INPUT_EMAIL,P.CMMT_RESULT,P.QUERY_RESULT,P.CMMT_SPEC                                   " 


ElseIf sReportType = "2" then           'Large Report Creation SQL String
    strTableWidth = "2800"              'Limit size of width

    subSQL = subSQL & " FROM PATIENT P, FU B WHERE P.PAT_ID = B.PAT_ID "
    
    subSQL2 = subSQL2 & " ,B.FU_KIND,B.FU_NO,B.LAB_DATE,B.WBC,DECODE(B.WBC_UNIT,'1','/mm<sup>3</sup>','2','/L','') AS WBC_UNIT,B.SEG_NEUTRO,B.BANDS, "
    subSQL2 = subSQL2 & " B.ANC,DECODE(B.STOP_KIND,'1','StopFollow','2','Terminate','') AS STOP_KIND,            " 
    subSQL2 = subSQL2 & " DECODE(B.STOP_CAUSE,'1','Irregular','2','Improve','3','Transfer','4','Others','') AS STOP_CAUSE,B.STOP_TRANS_NM,B.STOP_ETC,B.DOCTOR_NM,B.DOCTOR_EMAIL,B.PHARMA_NM,                 " 
    subSQL2 = subSQL2 & " B.PHARMA_EMAIL,B.INPUT_NM,B.INPUT_EMAIL,B.CMMT_RESULT,B.QUERY_RESULT,B.CMMT_SPEC               " 


End If

SQL2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) " & subSQL
tn = GetRecordCount(SQL2)

If sReportType = "1" then
    subSQL = subSQL & " ORDER BY P.HOSP_CD, P.RAND_DATE DESC, P.PAT_NM "
ElseIf sReportType = "2" then           
    subSQL = subSQL & " ORDER BY P.HOSP_CD, B.LAB_DATE DESC "

End If

qTitle = qTitle & " ]"

SQL = "     SELECT getHospNM(P.HOSP_CD) HOSP_NM, P.PAT_ID,P.HOSP_CD,P.RAND_DATE,P.PAT_NM,P.CHART_NO,P.DOB,P.AGE,P.SEX,P.FILENAME,P.PAT_WANDERING,P.PAT_WANDERING_NUM "
SQL = SQL &         subSQL2
SQL = SQL &         subSQL

set objRs=DbCon.Execute(SQL)

Response.buffer=true
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel; name='My_Excel'"
If sReportType = "1" then
    Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=small.xls"
ElseIf sReportType = "2" then       
    Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=Large.xls"

End If

sHTTP_HOST = request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST")
%>

<table> <tr>... 
    ' creating html table to print and start downloading file with ".xls" extension
    ...
<%
    Do While Not (objRs.BOF OR objRs.EOF)
        aaa = objRs("aaa")
        bbb = objRs("bbb")
        ccc = objRs("ccc")
    ...
    </tr>
<% 
    objRs.MoveNext
    Response.Flush
    
    Loop
    'end of table loop

    objRs.Close
    DbCon.close
    Set objRs = Nothing
    Set DbCon = Nothing
%>
</table>
```

Comment: For information about "Optimizing the Performance of Database Access in IIS", you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525484(v=vs.90)

Comment: Is buffering turned on? Are you sure that your are not exceeding the allocated buffer in IIS? If you think this may be the problem, try using either of these solutions: https://www.itnota.com/troubleshooting-response-buffer-limit-error-classic-asp/

Comment: It took sometime to verify and check those valuable comments though;

- Caching ADO and make it more space & time for the pooling did not worked
> Actual DB connections seems response correctly and took data as whole, but while its processing seems not an issue. However, IIS connection suddenly disconnected before complete transfer. HTTP connection drops prematurely before end of html. It also suspect that gradual tendency of premature disconnection increases. Of course, while it generate and transmit, other connection refused.

Comment: Turning off Page Buffer and increase IIS buffer also checked, but seems not working. Increased IIS buffer upto 100MB even, blocking other connection while processing ASP page html table continues. @derek-valdes-diaz , any other ideas? Should I change this to ASP.net or other application module type may solve this case?